# Shemonim Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows two hundred eighty?

### ?שמונים ומאתים - מי יודע

In the spirit of the song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea), please post interesting and significant Jewish facts about the number 280.

I'm feeling bullish about people's ability to make something of the lazy gematria this time.

Check out [mi-yodeya-series](/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) for the previous two hundred seventy-nine entries in this ongoing series.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99516/yasher-kochacha Feel free to delete this comment when done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 280 verses in the book of Ezra.

Answer (score 4):

By the Pitum HaKetores there are 4 items (Samonim) that have a weight of 70 Mana.

1 - Tzori

2 - Tziporen

3 - Chelbana

4 - Levona

4 x 70 = 280

Answer (score 2):

From when Avraham was born until Yitzchok passed away was 280 years. Avraham was 100 when Yitzchok was born and Yitzchok lived 180 years.

Answer (score 2):

280 days, the term of natural pregnancy

Comment: Note that this is not the first value for days in a pregnancy that has been entered in this series, and it probably won't be the last.

Answer (score 2):

דברי הימים ב: יד. ז.
ויהי לאסא חיל נשא צנה ורמח מיהודה שלש מאות אלף ומבנימן נשאי מגן ודרכי קשת **מאתים ושמונים** אלף כל אלה גבורי חיל

דברי הימים ב: יז. טו.
ועל ידו יהוחנן השר ועמו **מאתים ושמונים** אלף

I know its 280,000 however it will take way long till we get there.

Comment: There are only two or three significant figures in these numbers anyway. (In other words, I seriously doubt they're meant to be precise down to the individual soldier.) I'd say they're valid lechatchila for 280.

Answer (score 1):

> The Temple Mount is approximately rectangular, 488 meters (1,601
>   feet) on the western side, 471 meters (1,542 feet) on the eastern side,
>   315 meters (1033 feet) on the northern side, and **280 meters (919
>   feet) on the southern side**. The total area is about 150,000 square
>   meters (about 35.5 acres).

[Entering the Temple Mount—
in Halacha and Jewish History
By: GEDALIA MEYER and HENOCH MESSNER](http://www.hakirah.org/Vol%2010%20Messner.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Even if you are not bullish בכור בהמה which = 280 is mentioned 3 times in Tanach.